# VS launch executable from solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a visual studio solution and want an exe-file (not compiled by that solution) in the solution explorer which will be launched on double click.

It is possible to add the exe-file. But on double click resource editor shows meta data about that file. I might click "open with..." and add "cmd.exe /c" there but that entry will not persist.

Answer (score 0):

You can open your exe with Windows Explorer. Add "Windows Explorer" entry to the list when you select "Open With..." menu item. The path is "C:\Windows\explorer.exe"